# Logging postgres output messages from Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

In my Postgres9.6 RDS instance I have a trigger that I usually use to log suspicious data coming in:

```
create or replace function check_stuff()
returns trigger as
$$
declare passed boolean;
begin
    raise warning 'something weird happened';
    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER check_stuff_trigger
   BEFORE UPDATE ON important_table
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_stuff();
```

How can I configure Sequelize so I can receive and log those messages?

Comment: I think the easies solution is to move trigger functionality into [sequelize hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html), if it's not possible then, I think, you can store logs in some table and read them in application (again you can use hooks). I'm not sure whether it is possible to return the message thrown by trigger, but there's also option called [`returning`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html), maybe this option can help (but it works in postgresql only)?

Comment: @Logans hooks are not an option unfortunately, they're not powerful or general enough for the checks I'll be doing. As for `returning`, IIRC it'll just flag postgres to send back generated values. Messages are sent in a different "channel" (output) to postgres clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that `sequelize.js` has any functionality to read database messages such as the warning messages that you're raising.

However, I've had a bit of a look at `node-postgres` (which `sequelize` uses as its backend for PostgreSQL), which does appear to have an `.on('notice',...)` event on the `Client` object (which is what Sequelize uses for postgres connections). I imagine this event will trigger when the `RAISE WARNING` is executed on the connection.

Adding a `.on('notice', ...)` handler in the `afterConnect` Sequelize hook will achieve your aim of being able to log the `RAISE WARNING` messages; I've performed a test of the below code snippet and it works:

```
sequelize.addHook('afterConnect', (client) => {
  // "client" is a node-postgres Client instance when using the postgres dialect
  client.on('notice', (notice) => {
    // Filter to (for example) only log "RAISE WARNING" level messages
    if (notice.severity === 'WARNING') {
      console.log(`Received notice with severity ${notice.severity}: ${notice.message}`);
    }
  });
});
```

The `client` argument to `afterConnect` is a `node-postgres` `Client` instance in the PostgreSQL dialect case; see https://node-postgres.com/api/client#client-on-39-notice-39-notice-string-gt-void-gt-void for documentation. However, it looks like the doco is wrong since my testing shows that `.on('notice', (arg) => {...})`, `arg` is passed as an object, where the documentation suggests this should be a `string`.